# How to sum values in different positions in excel across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have around 40 worksheets in a workbook where each worksheet outlines steps in a process, with the total max and min times are summed at the bottom of each sheet.

The problem is, the total max and min times are in a different cell in each sheet. Luckily this value always appears to the right of a cell with the string "Total Max Time" and "Total Min Time" respectively, so I was thinking there could be a way to:

1. Step through each sheet
2. Find where in the page the "Total Max Time" string is
3. Offset by (0,1)
4. Add that value to a rolling total
5. Return the final value of the rolling total once each sheet has been stepped through, and present in a cell on the summary sheet.

I am not too familiar with VBA and would like to learn. Is there any way to do this and if so, how would I do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please share the layout of summary sheet. `present in a cell` what's the location of the cell?

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, **and the shortest code necessary** to reproduce the problem. *I am not too familiar with VBA and would like to learn* SO is not the place to learn coding but to solve specific coding problems. If you need to learn VBA then take a course

Answer (score 1):

Here is some commented code that should perform as described. I hope this helps you learn as a starting point.

```
Sub SumMaxTime()
    
    'Declare variables
    Dim wb As Workbook:         Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim wsSummary As Worksheet: Set wsSummary = wb.Worksheets("Summary")
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rFind As Range
    Dim dTotal As Double
    
    'Step through each worksheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> wsSummary.Name Then   'Skip summary worksheet
            'Find string "Total Max Time"
            Set rFind = ws.Cells.Find("Total Max Time", , xlValues, xlWhole)
            
            'Confirm the string was found
            If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
                'Add the value in the cell to the right to a running total
                dTotal = dTotal + rFind.Offset(, 1).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    
    'Output the total to the summary sheet
    'Change the cell address as needed
    wsSummary.Range("A1").Value = dTotal
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to go through this and learn what each line does and why you've done it. I really appreciate your feedback :)